# Adjust datetime in Pandas to get CustomBusinessWeek

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a long series of stock daily prices and I am trying to get week prices to do some calculations.  I have been reading the documentation and I see you can set offsets get a specific date of the week which is what I want.  This is the code assume stock is part of a loop I am runing.

```
df_clean_BW[WEEKLY_PricesFriday'] = stock.resample('W-FRI').last()
```

But for US stock market there are many days where it is a holiday on Friday so then I saw you can adjust this for USCalendar Holidays.  This is the code I was using

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import CustomBusinessDay
from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar
bday_us = CustomBusinessDay(calendar=USFederalHolidayCalendar())
```

But I dont know how to combine the two so that if there is a holiday on Friday to take the day prior (the Thursday instead). So something like this but this throws an error

```
df_clean_BW[WEEKLY_PricesFriday'] = stock.resample('W-FRI' & bday_us).last()
```

I have a long list of dates so I don't want to create a list of exception days because that would be too long.  Here is an example of the output I would want.  In this case Jan 1, 2016 was a Friday so I just want to take December 31, 2015 instead.  This must be a common request for anyone who looks at stock data but I cant figure out a way to do it.

```
Date         Price     Week Price
12/30/2015  103.3227
12/31/2015  101.3394
1/4/2016    101.426    101.3394   << Take 12/31 as 1.1 is holiday
1/5/2016    98.8844 
1/6/2016    96.9492 
1/7/2016    92.8575 
1/8/2016    93.3485     93.3485
```

Answer (score 1):

First generate your array of Fridays including holidays.  Then use [`np.busday_offset()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.busday_offset.html) to offset them like this:

```
np.busday_offset(fridays, 0, roll='backward', busdaycal=bday_us.calendar)
```